# Save entity with id created in code, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I do to pass the id of a document from outside and not that mongoose generates it?
I need the objects to be stored with the id I tell them, but mongoose overwrites it and saves it with the one he wants. I tried several ways now and nothing happens.

It is an entity that I am distributing through events in several databases, so I need it to be stored with the id I want to maintain the integrity of the data.

Now I have this and it says "document must have an _id before saving", but the id I have already put it, does not recognize it.
The scheme is like this:

```
const schema = new Schema({
_id: { type: String },
name : { type: String },
});
```

I also tried with this, and the error is the same:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    _id:  { type : String },
    name : { type: String },
},
{
    _id: false
});
```

I am passing the object like this:

```
Item.create({ _id: 'my uuid here', name: 'something' });
```

but when it is saved it remains with the id generated by mongoose replacing mine, that is, it changes it to me with a _id: '5twt563e3j5i34knrwnt43w'

Comment: i used the exact code you provided, and it worked (the id stored in db is : "my uuid here"): https://shrib.com/#Inf7xx99d3VpQ9UClN9_ so my suggestion is : create a new blank project, and use this code and check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax should work, but sometimes mongoose acts weird.

You can try this syntax (works on my project) :

```
const item = new Item({ name: 'something' });    
item._id = 'my uuid here';
await item.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a random uuid, you need to use a mongoDB objectID. Mongoose can also create that,

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

Store this id in the collection,

Item.create({ _id: id, name: 'something' });

Comment: its better to say `you better to` instead of `you need to`, because mongoose works with custom _id as well.